# Multiple INSERT INTO to one single row

Tags: sql-insert

I have two INSERT INTO statements to the same table...

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3)

INSERT INTO #TempTable (col4, col5, col6)
exec CheckComponent
```

how can I insert both to the same row on the #TempTable... using the current script, the 1st 3 columns are sent to row 1 while the last 3 columns are sent to row 2

This is what I getting right now:

[image: This is what I getting right now]

This is what I need to get:

[image: This is what I need to get]

thank you in advance for any help you can provide...

Comment: Can you include the stored proc `CheckComponent`, or at least tell us what it is doing?

Comment: Will you have a single row in this table? What database server are you using? Which column is the temporary table makes rows unique?

Comment: CheckComponent returns 3 values which later are going to be stored in #TempTable  Col4, Col5 and Col6

Comment: #TempTable is not having a single row, but all the 6 columns are one single record.. I don't want to have Col1, Col2 and Col3 in one row, and Col4, Col5 and Col6 on the next one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of options here.

1. use an update instead of an insert for the second half of the data.
2. Run the `EXEC CheckComponent` and insert it into a different temp table. Then you can use joins to combine the data on another insert.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3)

UPDATE #TempTable 
SET col = val , ...
WHERE pk = pkval
```

pk means primary key.